Which Debian 12 package contains the driver for Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S GT1?
I am looking for the driver corresponding to:
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 770] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Raptor Lake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 770]
        Kernel modules: i915
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port (rev 01)


I am on Debian 12.
I think it would be in firmware-linux-nonfree package, but I am not sure.
How do I look this up ?
Edit:
$  sudo dpkg -S i915_pci
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *i915_pci*
$ uname -a
Linux xxxxxx 6.1.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.106-3 (2024-08-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm

Why does it say that no path found ?
On a different computer, I did this:
sudo dpkg -S i915_pci
 
linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-6.1.0-25-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-25-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-6.1.0-22-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-22-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-20-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-5.10.0-26-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-26-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-6.1.0-23-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-23-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-6.1.0-26-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-26-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-6.1.0-17-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-17-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h
linux-headers-6.1.0-21-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-21-common/include/drm/i915_pciids.h

I guess I should install the linux-headers package by doing:
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Would I be doing the right thing?

Drivers for that GPU should already be included in the Debian 12 install, see this page:

The device is supported by kernel versions 5.17 and newer according to the LKDDb

Intel drivers are usually integrated into the kernel and Mesa, both of which (of course) come by default. You can then look up what kernel version your distribution uses. For Debian 12 it should be 6.1+. Best way to see what package exactly the drivers correspond to is to use dpkg -S with a file that should be a part of the package, and it will tell you which package it comes from. Example files are listed in the page linked above, one of them is:
drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_pci.c
